# Cypress freezing on multiple tests

Tags: cypress

When I run a suite of tests, Cypress is freezing on some tests. Different tests every time. At first I thought it was just tests that for some reason might take a while to run (like something that involves a timeout) but that doesn't seem to be the case. Running an individual test, with `describe.only` or `it.only`, does not freeze. Behavior is the same with `cypress run` in the command line.

When the test freezes, the spinner by the test in the Cypress pane still spins, but the app's UI is frozen -- for instance when my app's UI shows a spinner that spinner is frozen. Sometimes it even freezes on the `VISIT /` part of the test, before it even gets to any of the stuff that takes longer. Freezing happens in different spots, sometimes on different tests, on different cypress runs.

Also, even when a test file runs to completion, sometimes the Cypress UI (like the stop button at the top) doesn't respond.

This only started happening Friday, possibly coinciding with an update to 3.8.1. I've tried using 3.7.0 again, with no change.

Is anyone else experiencing this? I'm running on Windows 10 and the app is ReactJS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Linux there is a bug related to Chrome 79 that freezes Cypress. Check here for more info: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/24842699?hl=en

You can also update to latest Chrome version

Answer (score -1):

How the problem was finally resolved ?

I encounter same problem but for some reason load event does not trigger even after 60.000ms; - I test app on different resolutions and sometimes, app doesn't load in some resolutions.

Comment: Please consider using comment for such question. This is not an answer. 

Comment: @srgj: To your benefit, if you remove this "answer", you will improve your badge stats.